# Get the Treeview Parent From a TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I would to know if there is a mean to get the treview parent of a TreeViewItem programmactically or a turn around examples in WPF.
The goal is to have the DataContext of the TreeView in order to execute command from the ViewModel.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here, the xaml code. The AddDisplayProperty is part of the data context of the treeview.
My other problem is how to find the TreeViewItem from the TextBlock of the DataTemplate.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayProperties, Mode=OneWay}" MinHeight="20" AllowDrop="True">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <local:FrameworkElementCommandDropBehavior DropCommand="{Binding AddDisplayPropertyCommand}"  DropType="{x:Type local:SearchProperty}"/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <TreeView.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SearchProperty}">
                                <TextBlock Margin="5.0"  Text="{Binding Path=LongDescription, Mode=OneWay}" AllowDrop="True">
                                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <local:FrameworkElementCommandDropBehavior DropCommand="[Binding AddDisplayPropertyCommand}"  DropType="{x:Type local:SearchProperty}" DropParameters="{Binding}"/>
                                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.Resources>
                    </TreeView>
```

Comment: you can set the `RelativeSource` for your `Binding`s when you set your `Command`s. Could you show your XAML so that we can see how you create your treeview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this code at some point in time,  you just have to call ParentofType(treeviewItem) and it will give you the first Treeview it finds up the chain or null.

```
public T ParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (element == null)
    return default (T);
    else
    return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<T>(Enumerable.OfType<T>((IEnumerable) GetParents(element)));
}

public IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetParents( DependencyObject element)
{
    if (element == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
    while ((element = GetParent(element)) != null)
        yield return element;
}

private DependencyObject GetParent(DependencyObject element)
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    if (parent == null)
    {
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = element as FrameworkElement;
        if (frameworkElement != null)
            parent = frameworkElement.Parent;
    }
    return parent;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have solved my problem with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/332833fc-11c9-44d7-8d09-ab081ac0f28a/how-to-get-the-parent-of-a-treeviewitem-generated-by-itemsource-binding-in-a-treeview?forum=wpf). I think it explains how to do it, from code behind.

The datacontext in the example can be accessed using parent.DataContext